# Conditional formatting a pivot table using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply some VBA code that will compare several columns of data.

See image below (this conditional formatting is correct by the way):
[image]

In this instance, the values in column c are being compared to column B, E to D, G to F, I to H. A higher score is bad, so the conditional formatting is in all 2016 columns, if the value is greater than 2015, there should be a red down arrow, and a green arrow if the opposite is true.

Here is the code I've been using:

```
Sub ColorYear()
    Dim long1 As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Last used row
    long1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Delete existing rules
    Range("A7:U" & long1).FormatConditions.Delete
    ' Loop through the rows
    For t = 3 To long1
        For c = 5 To 21 Step 2 ' columns C,E,G,I
            With Cells(t, c).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition
                .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Triangles)
                .ReverseOrder = True
                With .IconCriteria(2)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "=" & Cells(t, c - 1).Address
                    .Operator = 7
                End With
                With .IconCriteria(3)
                    .Type = xlConditionValueFormula
                    .Value = "=" & Cells(t, c - 1).Address
                    .Operator = 5
                End With
            End With
        Next c
    Next t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works so long as there is no filtering applied. For instance, if there is no filter being applied cell C3 gets compared to B3. However, if I apply some filters, C2 gets compared to B3 (it's original cell), so the comparison is incorrect and gives me the wrong conditional formatting.

See image below (this is the incorrect formatting with filters applied):

[image]

Can anyone assist?

Comment: FWIW from a [ux.se] perspective, it's not immediately obvious why a *higher* number should have a *downward* red arrow, and a *lower* number should have an *upward* green arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditional logic to use constant expressions instead of cell addresses.

Add a column that calculates the difference between TY and LY, and make the icons conditional to the *difference* being `<0`, `>0`, or `=0`.

Also as I mentioned in comments:

> *FWIW from a User Experience perspective, it's not immediately obvious why a higher number should have a downward red arrow, and a lower number should have an upward green arrow.*

Consider using the colored circles icon set instead of arrows.

[image: colored circles]

That way you still convey "good", "neutral" and "bad", without implying an up/down direction that's contradicting the represented data.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Mat. The colored circles are a good idea. What do you mean by TY and LY? Also, instead of adding an additional column, is there a way to implement this logic into the VBA code itself? Reason being I have 16 columns that needs to be compared, so this would be a lot of additional columns. Plus, this is a pivot table, so I would need to use Calculated Fields which introduces a lot of additional steps.

Comment: That's "This Year" and "Last Year" ;-) if you can add the calculations in the pivot source data, you don't need calculated pivot fields. The problem is that, in my experience, pivot tables once formatted should be PDF'd as-is, else they wreck the formats. Avoiding cell references in formsts is the only way I've found to avoid that. Maybe someone else will have a better idea though.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. Hmm, as I think about it, adding an additional column in the data source might be easier said than done.These values are calculated fields to begin with, so adding the additional column in the data source would mean restructuring all of my existing data.

Comment: I always try to have as much of the calculations in the pivot source (using an actual Excel table (`ListObject`) as a data source), and only have calculated pivot fields for things that can't be aggregated with a `SUM`, e.g. profit margin percentages, which can't be added up and need to still work with aggregated subtotals.